# How to restore on another Ubuntu computer a MySQL backup made by rsnapshot?

Tags: backup, mysql, remote, restore, rsnapshot

How to restore on another Ubuntu computer a MySQL database backup made by rsnapshot on an external USB hard disk? 
This seems to be difficult because the UID and GID of mysql differ on both computers.

I could work around by determining UID and GID of mysql on the target computer, copying the database in `/var/log/mysql/` and running the command `~$ chown -R newuser:newgroup newdir`.

Is there a more straightforward solution?

[Backup on Ubuntu 12.04, Restore on Ubuntu 10.04.4]

Comment: Also, try asking at [dba.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is to make a mysqldump and restore from that.

`mysqldump -u root -p > iamateapot.sql` should save everything in mysql into `iamateapot.sql` stored in the current working directory.

Transfer that .sql to the other server, do `mysql -u root -p < iamateapot.sql`, and it'll overwrite all current MySQL data on that server with new data, and retain all users, pws, etc.  At least it should.